# PhpStorm don't show line status in editor

Tags: phpstorm

My PhpStorm ver7.0 doesn't show line status in editor (added lines, modified line, deleted lines). How can I show them (I installed Tortoise SVN and checkout my project)?

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have [enabled version control](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-subversion-integration.html) for the project directory in `Settings` | `Version Control`, just map the project root to Subversion.

Comment: I maped but nothing change.

Comment: Do you have .svn directory in the project root? What is the working copy format? Please perform the checkout from PhpStorm or using the 1.7 svn client version as [1.8 working copy format is not supported yet](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94942).

Comment: I recently discovered 1.8 working copy format is not supported yet:D . Uninstalled 1.8 and reinstalling 1.7. I will report later ! Thanks fot support

Comment: @DucPT  do you mean it's a bug for 1.8?